# Ubuntu sendmail spam

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron, sendmail

I have installed sendmail in Ubuntu to send mails and it works fine, but I have detected that every 30' I receive an e-mail with this subject:

> Cron  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x
>   /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] &&
>   /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)

And every 20 minutes I receive this other e-amil with this subject:

> Cron  test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail &&
>   /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp

What happened? How can I avoid to send this e-mails?

Comment: Which `sendmail*` packages have you installed? `dpkg -l 'sendmail*'`

Comment: I've got this exit .... 

ii  sendmail-base  8.14.4-4.1ub all          powerful, efficient, and scalable
rc  sendmail-bin   8.14.4-4.1ub amd64        powerful, efficient, and scalable
ii  sendmail-cf    8.14.4-4.1ub all          powerful, efficient, and scalable
un  sendmail-doc   <ninguna>    <ninguna>    (no hay ninguna descripción disponible)

Comment: I've got this four package: 
sendmail-base /
sendmail-bin /
sendmail-cf /
sendmail-doc